# How many circuits can I add to a 50 amp subpanel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel, construction

I’m working with a sub panel that is rated up to 125 amp max. Currently it is wired with 6 gauge and has a 50 amp breaker in the main. How much more load can I put on the sub panel or how many more outlets can I add to the sub panel?

There will be a washer/dryer, roughly 20 outlets, 4 lights including a fan and a bathroom exhaust fan. And 2 exterior light. Is it safe to add this many outlets and breakers to a sub panel running off these conditions.

Comment: That seems to be too much load to place on a 50 amp service. I would look to upgrade to at least 90amp if not the whole 125.

Comment: If those are what you are **adding,** what's **already on it?** For the outlets/lighting, how many square feet are being served? Is the dryer gas, electric-resistance, electric-but-heat-pump?

Comment: What is the cable type/insulation type? NM?

Comment: Where in the world are you different areas have different requirements for residential. You have 3 circuits that are specified by code , the bathroom, washing machine are both 20 A 1500va calculated value the dryer 30 amp 240v  you could put all the other receptacles on 1 breaker but that’s not wise as Harper is thinking you could jump to a 60 amp feeder and you would be fine in most cases. Where you would not be fine if the exterior are high wattage and the inside receptacles are all running heavy loads like table saw, dust collector, chop saw, without knowing the loads you might be fine now.

Comment: 6 gauge is rated/recommended for 50 amps usually.  Any upgrades of power will require replacement of the wire/cable to larger gauge.  Depending on type and material of the wire.  Will also depend on the load that the main panel has now if you can increase the sub panel's power

Comment: How many *square feet* of building area does this subpanel serve?

Comment: @crip659 that is a 125 amp panel so the feeder ampacity is 65 if all parts are 75c rated.  feeders are actual per the NEC 215.2.A.1  if a non continuous load you can by code connect 65 amps to #6 wire.